# How do I reconfigure and compile a website to Framework 3.5 using asp.net in VS2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, frameworks, .net-3.5

Firstly I want to make it clear that I am not a programmer.

My predicament is that I had a website developed for me in asp.net, programmed in C# and with Framework 4.0. The developer who programmed it is in America for a month and I can't get hold of him! I urgently need to change the Framework to 3.5. The reason for this is that my hosting service doesn't support 4.0.

So, I have got a folder with, what can only be described as A MILLION files and sub-folders. I have opened a "new project from existing files" in VS2010 and set the framework in properties to 3.5, also changed the framework target script in the web.config file. Now this is where I lose track of what to do next. I assume I would need to compile the project and export it, but how do I do that? I mean what format should it be exported as in order for me to update all the Framework and publish the files to the web?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Project (the top item normally) in Solution Explorer, and hit Publish, this should then take you through to ask you where you want to put the files